# Remove "Image Zoom" effect when stop scrolling on smartphone

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, zooming

I have issue with woo image zoom effect when tap on image on [my site](https://www.yeswedress.fr/produits/robes/robes-evenements/robes-cocktails/). When scroll on smartphone is all fine, but when tap on product thumbnail, image is zoom, and its not showing in full size. I want to remove that thing into smartphone look only. For example here is shown the issue:

[issue on smartphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujMcm.png)

I have tryed to fix this issue via CSS, but without success. This is CSS from image section:

```
.et_overlay {
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
opacity: 0;
background: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
-webkit-transition: all .3s;
-moz-transition: all .3s;
transition: all .3s;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-backface-visibility: hidden
}

.et_overlay:before {
position: absolute;
top: 55%;
left: 50%;
margin: -16px 0 0 -16px;
font-size: 32px;
content: "\e050";
-webkit-transition: all .4s;
-moz-transition: all .4s;
transition: all .4s
}
```

EDIT: Tryed this function also, but without success:

```
function remove_image_zoom_support() {
remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
}
add_action( 'wp', 'remove_image_zoom_support', 100 );
```

Any help how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like added this CSS, removed Zoom feature from Woo thumb on smartphones:

```
.et_shop_image {
pointer-events:none!important;
}
```